# Put braces in in-line math outside or inside of math-mode $?

Tags: math-mode, braces, inline

Is there a consensus on which approach is better:

```
text ($like this$) more text
```

or

```
text $(like this)$ more text
```

if the content is not anything special, i.e. does not require `\left(\right)`?

Thanks.

Comment: It's easy: if the parentheses are part of the formula, they go inside, otherwise outside. By the way, `\left` and `\right` are *never* required. They *can* be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
If the widget ($\chi^2$) is foobar then the vector $(a,b,c)$ is zzzzz.
```

The first pair of brackets is part of the text sentence structure and the second is part of the mathematics.

Comment: This is a good and straight-forward approach that is also independent of LaTeX, as @egreg already explained. I was making it too complicated. Thanks.